# JavaScript, I cannot get value of input on this way?

Tags: javascript

I cannot get value of input, why? Thanks for your answer!
This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="fullname"/>
    <button id="button">button</button>
</body>
    <script>
        var name = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
        var btn = document.getElementById("button");
        btn.onclick = function(){alert(name)};
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code. Post it as text here, not as image links. Use `{ }` in the SO editor to mark it as literal code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Script tag need to be in the body tag
2. You need to get the value when you have entered it

Working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xr6uCjPvGpskgceb125K)

```
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("button");

    btn.onclick = function(){
      var name = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
      alert(name);
    };
</script>
```